# int32_t to int64_t (or to float)

Tags: c, casting

I have a very simple algorithm written in C, which takes values from array of `int16_t`, multiplies those values by their positions and stores into array of `int32_t`. There is another variable `sum` of type `int64_t` storing sum of all values in the resulting `_slops` array. Here is the code.

```
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)

// these variables initialized separately

int16_t *from;
int32_t *_slops;
int32_t _overlapSize;
...

// main algorithm

int32_t pos;
int64_t sum = 0;
for(pos = 0; pos < _overlapSize; pos++) {
    _slops[pos] = (from[pos] * pos * (_overlapSize - pos));
    sum += (int64_t) _slops[pos];
    if (pos == 2) {
        LOGD("1 ---: %d", (from[pos] * pos * (_overlapSize - pos)));
        LOGD("2 ---: %d", _slops[pos]);
        LOGD("3 sum: %d", sum);
    }
}
LOGD("sum: %d", sum);
```

When I run the code, I see that resulting array of `_slops` has correct values in it, but the `sum` variable has same value all the time.

```
02-26 15:58:10.762: D/player(17466): 1 ---: 1154560
02-26 15:58:10.762: D/player(17466): 2 ---: 1154560
02-26 15:58:10.762: D/player(17466): 3 sum: 1504780888
02-26 15:58:10.762: D/player(17466): sum: 1504780904

02-26 15:58:10.840: D/player(17466): 1 ---: 890560
02-26 15:58:10.840: D/player(17466): 2 ---: 890560
02-26 15:58:10.848: D/player(17466): 3 sum: 1504780888
02-26 15:58:10.848: D/player(17466): sum: 1504780904

02-26 15:58:10.848: D/player(17466): 1 ---: 1791680
02-26 15:58:10.848: D/player(17466): 2 ---: 1791680
02-26 15:58:10.848: D/player(17466): 3 sum: 1504780888
02-26 15:58:10.848: D/player(17466): sum: 1504780904
```

I tried to change type of `sum` to `float`, but the result stayed the same. I am quite sure I do something wrong with type casting (`int32_t` to `int64_t` or `int32_t` to `float`), but I wasn't able to find the right way for doing it.

What is the right way for doing this in C? And in general, if I multiply two `int16_t` values, and what to have a larger result (let's say `int32_t`), how do I do this? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you remove the cast of the value you are adding to sum?

Comment: @ScottHunter no change, sum stays the same

Comment: @MichaelWalz That was a left over from example code adaptation. I removed it.

Comment: How is LOGD implemented?

Comment: @jxh This is Android log. I added a define.

Comment: For troubleshooting, I would add the "sum" logging statement inside the loop with the others and log on every iteration and not just on iteration 2.  That would get you a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for helping, guys! @jxh I will accept your answer if you write it. After I replaced "%d" with "%lld", the value changes as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless `int64_t` is an alias for `int` on your machine, you are using the wrong `printf` format directive. Try this instead:

```
LOGD("sum: %" PRId64, sum);
```

`PRId64` is a macro defined in `<inttypes.h>`.

If you are using GCC, compiling with `-Wformat` would have generated an error about a format mismatch. `-Wall` will include `-Wformat`, along with many other useful warnings.

To your second question (about how to widen a result of a binary arithmetic operation that uses narrow type arguments), this is done by making at least one of the operands the width you desire. This can be done with a cast:

```
int16_t a = A_VAL;
int16_t b = B_VAL;
int32_t c = a + (int32_t)b;
```

As indicated by [maverik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/644350/maverik)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22045476/315052), you have a possibility for signed integer overflow in the expression that is assigned to `_slops[pos]`. If `_overlapSize` is greater than 2<sup>9</sup>, then the largest product of `pos * (_overlapSize - pos)` is greater than 2<sup>16</sup>, meaning its product against `from[pos]` could have a result greater than 2<sup>31</sup>.

Comment: @beworker: You are very welcome. If you use `%lld`, you should cast `sum` to `long long`, because in the general case, you don't really know the type for `int64_t` (on some machines, it might be a `long`, and `long long` could be something wider).

Comment: I like to use macro you mentioned, but Eclipse shows compilation error when I use it. That's why I checked how PRId64 defined and used "lld".

Answer (score 3):

Here is the problem:

```
_slops[pos] = (from[pos] * pos * (_overlapSize - pos));
```

The `_slops[pos]` is a type of `int32_t`. The expression `(from[pos] * pos * (_overlapSize - pos))` in some cases cannot be stored in `int32_t` because `from[pos]` is `int16_t` is multiplied by `pos` which is `int32_t` and the result can be bigger than `int32_t` (consider maximum value for `int16_t` that is `2^15` and maximum value for `int32_t` that is `2^31`. `2^15` * `2^31` = `2^46` which can't be stored as `int32_t` without truncating.

But you write it back to `_slops[pos]` which is `int32_t`. In this line:

```
sum += (int64_t) _slops[pos];
```

cast is useless and doesn't prevent narrowing. I suggest change `_slops` type to `int64_t *` or to use temporary variable to calculate the result:

```
int64_t tmp = ((int64_t) from[pos] * pos * (_overlapSize - pos));
```

I don't know how big can the `pos` be but the overall expression is not safe in this sense.

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. I reuse `pos` in many places in this method, that's why int32_t. In that particular loop it's not bigger than 5000.